# share point web app on access: on update data macro causes infinte loop

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint-2010, office365, ms-access-data-macro

I am working a SharePoint web app that keeps track of tickets associated with projects. I am trying to calculate the amount of time till a ticket is due, and the time complete a ticket using the datediff function that is performed as an on update data macro.The macro also populates a field named sloth based on the status of the ticket, a screenshot of the macro can be seen below. when I try and update on of the fields in the datasheet view I get an error that states I have created an infite loop. Thanks for the help :-)

- [here is a link to the data macro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXKfO.png)
- [The table the macro runs on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P03Mh.png)

Answer (score 0):

It not clear why you have two edit record blocks of code. Also, you don't mention what event you using, but you want to use the Before change event. This event occurs before the write and ALSO does not require you to use edit record boock, but only use set field. By using the after update event and a edit record, then you cause the after update event to trigger over and over. If you do a editrecord, then it triggers the after update event, which as  you see will then run over and over. Try before change event.